# HL7 HAPI - Unicode character \E appearing?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I'm making a character conversion to unicode using Java, sometimes I get a character "\E" in the converted String, what does this character mean?
- I searched and could not find an answer.

- This is a nice unicode converter: https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/
- And this page has all the codes: https://unicode-table.com
- This is the java code I used in case it might help:

> String conc = String.format ("\u%04x", (int)charArray[i]);

- This is an example of the output I'm getting:
  \E\u0645\E\u0644\E\u0641\E\u0020\E\u062a\E\u062c\E\u0631\E\u0628\E\u0629\E\u0020\E\u0644\E\u062a\E\u0642\E\u0646\E\u064a\E\u0629\E\u0020
- The output is correct if I remove all the "\E"

Comment: `conc` cannot contain a string which begins with **\E**. How do you get your "output"?

Comment: @fantaghirocco it's an arabic String so it's RTL, maybe that's why. I get my output using Oracle EM for SOA Suite (Enterprise Manager) and when I send the message on TCP/IP, it arrives same as above. What is \E ?

Answer (score 1):

All your backslashes are getting escaped to \E\ as this is the escape sequence used in HL7 for a backslash character.

For more information on escape sequences used  for special characters in HL7 you can refer to this link: https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-escape-sequences/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer so I'm sharing it for anyone who comes across a similar problem.
I was using HAPI - an HL7 lib for Java- which has a particular behavior of escaping the / with a /E when converting xml to a HL7v2 message, as the default seperator is the slash "/", that's why I was getting all the /E's.